# Insecure dependency in eval while running with -T switch on perl and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: perl

I have a small issue with the following line of text when loading the apache website of foswiki on Ubuntu 16.04.

**Error:**

> Foswiki detected an internal error - please check your Foswiki logs and webserver logs for more information.

Insecure dependency in eval while running with -T switch

**Log from error.log:**

> Insecure dependency in eval while running with -T switch at /var/www/Foswiki-1.1.9/lib/Foswiki.pm line 3153.

**Background: **

- Originally the VM was on ubuntu 12.04 and running foswiki 1.1.9.
- then I ran the upgrade on ubuntu and made it to 14.04 and was able to make the apache webservice work for foswiki.
- then I upgraded it to ubuntu 16.04 and seeing the error above.
- on ubuntu 12.04: perl version was 5.14
- on ubuntu 16.04: perl version is 5.22

Note: I have very limited knowledge in programming language and I need to upgrade this VM all the way up to ubuntu 20.04 LTS or 22.04 what ever I can.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: Running eval on unsafe data is about as unsafe as it gets. Taint mode (-T) is designed to prevent you from making mistakes like that.

Comment: If we wanted to help you, then one of the first things we might want to do is to copy your code into an editor to take a closer look at it. But we can't do that as you've only given us an image. And I'm not going to retype all of that. Code is text; please don't post images of it.

Answer (score 1):

The program was run using `perl -T` or as a setuid/setgid script, which enables [taint mode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec#Taint-mode). Taint mode prevents user inputs from being used in certain operations for security purposes. This is particularly appropriate for a web script.

Changes to the program or module will be needed to resolve the issue. Please consult their authors.

Answer (score -1):

Found the workaround to this problem:

1. all the scripts in this location: \var\www\Foswiki-1.1.9\
2. removed the -wT from the scripts and started working fine.

Comment: hmmm... First of all, there's no reason to remove `-w` here. And while you can stop using taint mode (by removing `-T`), this is a bad idea. If taint mode finds problems, your code possibly has some very nasty security issues. You should fix them instead.